# Selected tab does not have a title

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I am using a TabFragmentManager (while using a single RecyclerView and one Fragment) and the selected tab does not have a title on it. When I change tab the title is appearing to the previous tab.

```
public class TabFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;

public TabFragmentAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return new BaseFragment();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor =sp.edit();
            editor.putString(Constants.CONCERT_RV_KEY, "concerts");
        return mContext.getString(R.string.tab_recommended);
        case 1:
            sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            editor =sp.edit();
            editor.putString(Constants.CONCERT_RV_KEY, "artists");
            return mContext.getString(R.string.tab_tracked);
        case 2:
            sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            editor =sp.edit();
            editor.putString(Constants.CONCERT_RV_KEY, "concerts");
            return mContext.getString(R.string.tab_near_you);
        case 3:
           return mContext.getString(R.string.tab_attending);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Check what is the selected tab text color

Comment: omg.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selected tab text color like following

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabTextColor="#000000"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#00FF00"/>
```